# Azure Batch Pool Start up task to download resource file from Blob FileShare

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-batch

I'm new to Azure, and I'm trying to build a simple Azure batch case here.

I'm stacking at the Batch Pool Start up task...

I created a batch account and a storage account in East US, and then I created a general -- Fileshare in the storage account with a container. I manually updated a file called Test.txt.

What I want to do is to ask the Batch Pool to download this file at the startup task.

So Code goes:

```
string storageConnectionString = String.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}", StorageAccountName, StorageAccountKey);

// Retrieve the storage account
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
SharedAccessFilePolicy fileShareConstraint = new SharedAccessFilePolicy
{
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(48),
    Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read,
};
var fileShare = fileClient.GetShareReference(inputContainerName);
var rootDir = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
var testFile = rootDir.GetFileReference("test.txt");
var sasUrl = fileShare.GetSharedAccessSignature(fileShareConstraint);
var fileUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}", testFile.StorageUri.PrimaryUri, sasUrl);

var list = new List<ResourceFile>();
var testResourceFile = new ResourceFile(fileUrl, "test.txt");

list.Add(testResourceFile );
await CreatePoolAsync(batchClient, PoolId, list);
```

Then the CreatePoolAsync method:

```
private static async Task CreatePoolAsync(BatchClient batchClient, string poolId, IList<ResourceFile> resourceFiles)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Creating pool [{0}]...", poolId);

    // Create the unbound pool. Until we call CloudPool.Commit() or CommitAsync(), no pool is actually created in the
    // Batch service. This CloudPool instance is therefore considered "unbound," and we can modify its properties.

    //if(await batchClient.PoolOperations.GetPoolAsync(poolId) == null)
    //{

    CloudPool pool = batchClient.PoolOperations.CreatePool(
        poolId: poolId,
        targetDedicated: 1,                                                         // 3 compute nodes
        virtualMachineSize: "small",                                                // single-core, 1.75 GB memory, 225 GB disk
        cloudServiceConfiguration: new CloudServiceConfiguration(osFamily: "4"));   // Windows Server 2012 R2
    pool.MaxTasksPerComputeNode = 2;

    // Create and assign the StartTask that will be executed when compute nodes join the pool.
    // In this case, we copy the StartTask's resource files (that will be automatically downloaded
    // to the node by the StartTask) into the shared directory that all tasks will have access to.
    pool.StartTask = new StartTask
    {
        // Specify a command line for the StartTask that copies the task application files to the
        // node's shared directory. Every compute node in a Batch pool is configured with a number
        // of pre-defined environment variables that can be referenced by commands or applications
        // run by tasks.

        // Since a successful execution of robocopy can return a non-zero exit code (e.g. 1 when one or
        // more files were successfully copied) we need to manually exit with a 0 for Batch to recognize
        // StartTask execution success.

        CommandLine = "cmd /c (robocopy %AZ_BATCH_TASK_WORKING_DIR% %AZ_BATCH_NODE_SHARED_DIR%) ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% LEQ 1 exit 0",
        //CommandLine = "cmd /c net use E: \\krisblob2.file.core.windows.net\\krisfilecontiner1 /u:krisblob2 aqTFKyPqcpeI3BrEnlx8RTBAmDaN5FK+mxpBtdgn3v6IT+IbPgDhVU4ojRA1wAmMpYPEHQ9Gzh/A1mAHtxNs+A==",
        //CommandLine = $@"cmd /c net use Z: \\{StorageAccountName}.file.core.windows.net\krisfilecontiner1 /u:{StorageAccountName} {StorageAccountKey}",
        //CommandLine = "cmd /c %AZ_BATCH_TASK_WORKING_DIR%\\WinPcap_4_1_3.exe /passive",
        ResourceFiles = resourceFiles,
        WaitForSuccess = true
    };
}
```

The inputcontainer was the name I gave to the container in the file share.

When I ran the code, the startup task always failed with error:

**BlobDownloadMiscError Message**

> Miscellaneous error encountered while
>   downloading one of the specified Azure Blob(s) Details   The value for
>   one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
>   RequestId:944807de-001a-00bb-73ae-4ac746000000
>   Time:2016-11-30T02:04:59.8679984Z

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Just tried with your code, didn't encounter this issue...Could you tell me which line threw the error?

Comment: Actually the error was found in the Azure portal Pool Start up task info. Basically when the Compute node joining the Pool, and trying to download the resoucefile that I specified.

Comment: That's it, same error on my side after the node is created and started. I'll check and get back later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Batch [resource files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.resourcefile) can only be sourced from Azure Blob Storage and not Azure File Storage.

You will need to `net use` mount the share and copy the files manually or move your files to Azure Blob storage instead.

Comment: Seems that's the correct one! After map the drive the compute node can access to the files in it! Thank a lot!