# How to uncompress rar files using Azure DataFactory

Tags: azure, compression, azure-data-factory

We have a new client, while landing the project we gave them a blob storage for them to leave files so we could later automate and process the information.

The idea is to use Azure Datafactory but we find no way of dealing with .rar files, and even .zip, being it files from windows, are giving us trouble. And since it is the clien giving the .rar format, we wanted to make absolutely sure there is no way to process before asking them to change it, or deploying a databricks or similar service just for the purpose of transforming the file.

Is there any way to get a .rar file from a blob storage, uncompress it, then process it?

I have been looking in posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58441630) and related official documentation and closest we have come is using ZipDeflate, but it does not seem to fill our requirement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Compression only supported types are GZip, Deflate, BZip2, and ZipDeflate. .rar file is not supported for now.

Comment: For the [Unsupported file types and compression formats][1], Data Factory provides some workarounds.

Comment: Hi @monkey intern, if the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data factory compression only supported types are GZip, Deflate, BZip2, and ZipDeflate.

For the [Unsupported file types and compression formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs-legacy#compression-support), Data Factory provides some workarounds for us:

You can use the extensibility features of Azure Data Factory to transform files that aren't supported. Two options include Azure Functions and custom tasks by using Azure Batch.

You can see a sample that uses an Azure function to [extract the contents of a tar file](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/master/SamplesV2/UntarAzureFilesWithAzureFunction). For more information, see [Azure Functions activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity).

You can also build this functionality using a custom dotnet activity. Further information is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity).

Next way, you may need to figure out how to using Azure function to extract the contents of a rar file.

Answer (score 1):

you can use logic apps
you can use webhook activity calling a runbook

both are easiee than using a custom activity